# How to specify multiple fields in Fetch Place call?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, google-places

I'm a newbie so pardon me if this question is silly.
I'm using the nuget package Xamarin.Google.ios.Places and I'm trying to get Place Details from PlaceID after an AutocompleteFetcher call by using FetchPlace like so:

```
public void DidAutocomplete(AutocompletePrediction[] predictions)
{
    placeid = predictions.FirstOrDefault().PlaceId;
    var fields = new List();

    fields.Add(PlaceField.Name);
    fields.Add(PlaceField.FormattedAddress);
    fields.Add(PlaceField.PhoneNumber);
    fields.Add(PlaceField.OpeningHours);
    fields.Add(PlaceField.Photos);
    PlacesClient.SharedInstance.FetchPlace(placeid, fields, token, PlaceResultHandler);
}
```

But It's giving me an error in the "fields" parameter because it's expecting a Google.Places.PlaceField instead of a System.Collections.Generic.List, like described in the metadata

> public virtual void FetchPlace(string placeId, PlaceField placeFields,
>   AutocompleteSessionToken sessionToken,
>   [BlockProxy(typeof(NIDPlaceResultHandler))] PlaceResultHandler
>   callback);

It's there another way of doing this? if so, can someone direct me to the right direction?

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to [Place sdk for ios](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/place-id#example-using-the-places-sdk-for-ios).

Try to change like:

```
public void DidAutocomplete(AutocompletePrediction[] predictions)
{
    placeid = predictions.FirstOrDefault().PlaceId;
    PlaceField fields = PlaceField.Name | PlaceField.FormattedAddress | PlaceField.PhoneNumber | PlaceField.OpeningHours | PlaceField.Photos;
    PlacesClient.SharedInstance.FetchPlace(placeid, fields, token, PlaceResultHandler);
}
```